# Mysql Count row data by every date but only have few data date

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have a table "activity" like this

```
idEmployee  | activity | Date
1           | a        | 2019/01/01
1           | b        | 2019/01/01
2           | c        | 2019/01/01
2           | d        | 2019/01/01
1           | e        | 2019/01/02
2           | f        | 2019/01/03
1           | f        | 2019/01/03
3           | c        | 2019/01/01
4           | d        | 2019/01/03
1           | e        | 2019/01/02
2           | f        | 2019/01/03
```

and i want to count every date from 2019/01/01 - 2019/01/03 that has no activity by every idEmpolyee (as total_no_actitivity) like this

```
idEmployee | total_no_activity
1          | 0
2          | 1 (2019/01/02
3          | 2 (2019/01/02,2019/01/03)
4          | 2 (2019/01/01,2019/01/02)
```

but i only can select idemployee that has no activity , without count total_no_activity.

```
SELECT idEmployee, namaLengkap, date
FROM account LEFT JOIN timesheet USING (idEmployee)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT idEmployee
                  FROM timesheet
                  WHERE account.idEmployee = timesheet.idEmployee AND weekday(date) AND date                    between '2019/08/05' and '2019/08/09' AND idrole = '4' AND statusaktif = '1' )
ORDER BY idEmployee ASC
```

is it possible to count total_no_activity with table "activity" only?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT idEmployee, 
       3 - COUNT(DISTINCT `Date`) total_no_activity
FROM account
WHERE `Date` BETWEEN `2019/01/01` AND `2019/01/03`
GROUP BY idEmployee
```

where `3` is the amount of days in the period if interest, inclusive.

If some `idEmployee` have no records at all in the period in interest then this value will not be listed in output.

---

> unfortunately i need the idEmployee that have no records will be listed in the output

Assiming that you need all `idEmployee` values which are present in source table at least once (maybe even out of the period in interest) use

```
SELECT account.idEmployee, 
       3 - COUNT(DISTINCT account.`Date`) total_no_activity
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT idEmployee FROM account) all_employees
LEFT JOIN account USING (idEmployee)
WHERE account.`Date` BETWEEN `2019/01/01` AND `2019/01/03`
GROUP BY account.idEmployee
```

Comment: well, unfortunately i need the idEmployee that have no records will be listed in the output. is there any hope?

Comment: @AdikaraPerkasa Where such `idEmployee` may be taken from? The variant when the employees list is collected from the same table is added.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

```
select a.idEmployee,
       (datediff(params.date2, params.date1) + 1 - 
        count(distinct ac.date)
       ) as missing_days
from (select date('2019-01-01') as date1, date('2019-01-03') as date2
     ) params cross join   -- a convenience so we don't have to retype the constants
     accounts a left join
     activity ac
     on ac.idEmployee = a.idEmployee and
        ac.date >= params.date1 and
        ac.date <= params.date2
group by a.idEmployee;
```

To prevent typos and to allow the dates to change easily, this introduces a subquery, `params`, that has the date values.